# Can mass different log-in pages result in SEO duplicate and/or low quality punishments?

Tags: seo, google, duplicate-content

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

I have internal pages that rely on an external API which I would like to build upon user request. Two options I thought about:

1. Make lots of 'thin' pages that specifies that if you want content about X, you need to log-in, and then the page will be built. Pros: user understands what he'll get when logging in. Cons: SEO implications of such a solution due to the mass 'low quality' and 'cross-sites duplicate content'
2. Make them all redirect to ONE same generic log-in page. Pros: No duplicate low quality content. Cons: Lots of internal links to the same log-in page.

Which would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally go with option 2.  The test cases behind option 1 seem like they will become unmanageable in the near future as more and more login pages are created.

Comment: Thx. Is there a problem with having many inbound links that point to the same 'thin' log-in page?

Comment: I can't see why.  Any site that has a "login" link in the top corner of their browser would have that link on each page as well.